# date of birth format in selenium web driver in java program

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, firefox

In Calender , elements are not moving to previous and next button and middle how to write code  in selenium, webdriver in java program.

i tryed this below code 
    package com.s3sales.demo;

```
/*import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
*/
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions; 

public class S3sales {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://sssamriddhisales.com/crm");

        driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("admin");

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin123");     

        Thread.sleep(3000); 

        driver.findElement(By.className("btn-success")).click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

         WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Employee"));

         Thread.sleep(1000);

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-id='empRegistration']"))).click().build().perform();

    Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.findElement(By.id("newEmployee")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("empFirstName")).sendKeys("Rakesh");

        driver.findElement(By.id("empLastName")).sendKeys("Yadav");

        String dateTime ="1993-10-09";

        // button to open calendar
        driver.findElement(By.id("empDob")).click();

        WebElement nextLine=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='next']"));

        nextLine.click();

        //button to move next in calendar
    /*
         Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);

           WebElement driver1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[th(@class,'pre')]"));

           driver1.click();*/
         /*  WebElement prevLine = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[th@class='prev']"));

           prevLine.click();
     */
    }   
}
```

[image]

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: //div[@class='next']

no such elements found showing in console where and getting unable to locate element showing, please help me..

Comment: are you trying to click on next button of date picker?

Comment: image and error

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you trying to click on next button of date picker panel locator(`//div[@class='next']`) 
   for it is not exist and another locator `//th[@class='next']` may not work in some cases 
   as it has 4 matching nodes in DOM.
   you can try to click on next button using expected condition(explicit wait) as below

   `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='datepicker-days']//th[@class='next']")));

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='datepicker-days']//th[@class='next']")).click();`
2. you need not to automate entire date picker panel as you can see after inputing value in date input field it shows in panel, doing so input element locator was bit tedious to find unique match, you can find it below.

   ```
   String dateTime ="1993-10-09";
   String[] output = dateTime.split("-");
   String year = output[0];
   String day = output[2];
   String[] day1 = day.split("");
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
   ```

   `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//section[@class='section newSec none']/div//input[@id='empDob']")));`

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@class='section newSec none']/div//input[@id='empDob']")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@class='section newSec none']/div//input[@id='empDob']")).sendKeys(dateTime);

   //Wait until date is clickable in datepicker panel

   String datexpath = "//th[contains(text(),' "+year+"')]/ancestor::table//td[text()='"+day1[1]+"']";
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(datexpath)));
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(datexpath)).click();
   ```
3. If you really want to automate entire date picker panel you can refer this [tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/handling-date-time-picker-using-selenium.html) to automate date pickers

hope this solves your problem, let me know if it works for you or any doubts you have !!!

Answer (score 0):

the next element is present in the th tag not the div tag, so the xpath should be :

```
//th[@class='next']
```